# Как добавить и закоммитить файлы, измененные сегодня

Tags: linux, git, git-add, git-commit

Есть необходимость сделать коммит только тех файлов, которые я изменил за сегодня. Изменения в других файлах, которые я делал ранее, при этом должны остаться на месте.

Работаю на debian.

Comment: Можно добавить в stage только те файлы, которые нужно закоммитить. Команда: git add <имя файла>, затем git commit -m "Some message"

Comment: @zhenyab, ну да, в крайнем случае так и сделаю, а пока гуглю - в линуксе явно можно сделать это автоматичнее и проще

Comment: чтобы разделять коммиты есть git stash, но это на будущее, а пока придется вручную добавлять файлы и/или директории. Еще некоторые IDE предоставляют возможность делать выборочно коммиты.

Comment: @zhenyab, скорее всего, не придется - уже почти набросал такую строку find priject_dir/ -type f -mmin -500 -exec git add {} \; нужно только решить ошибку, которая выскакивает в случае применения команды к файлу из .gitignore

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
find project_fir/ -type f -mmin -500 -exec git add {} \;
```

https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Find